# How to fetch Value from Excel cell with formula ? Openpyxl data_Only flag doesn't work properly

Tags: python, pandas, excel-formula, openpyxl, xlwings

I have a automation script, in which openpyxl writes some data into Excel file. 
And that Excel file has some Formulas.
On next step i want to fetch that formulated cell value in python using openpyxl or Pandas, but OpenpyXl return as `None` and pandas return as `Nan` .
I know about Xlwings, but unfortunately xlwings doesn't work in Linux.

If there are any other workaround and working in Linux, please let me know. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Xlrd module can read the cell value, even it has formula. try the below code
Mark it as solved if it works.

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("excel.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
value= sheet.cell_value(1, 1)
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to save the document first and then reopen it. You could try using xlwings or the win32 module to save as.